# Disable alarms for all day events in google calendar

Tags: calendar, notifications

When I have an all-day event in my calendar (a friend's birthday perhaps) I find that my phone will notify me to the start of the event at 11:50pm the previous day and every few minutes after that.

Generally I don't need a notification for all day events, but find notifications for events with a specific time to be useful.

Is there a way to disable notifications for all-day events?

Or is there a way to disable calendar notifications between say 11pm and 8am (I'd be happy if the alerts sounded after I woke up) but I imagine that's harder to set up.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3807 Just found this issue that seems unresolved.

Comment: It's seems that the answer may well be to just be attentive to the alerts when creating events as the default alert is for both types of event in Google calendar itself.

Comment: Or set the event for 8am on your friend's birthday, instead of "all day" :)

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/how-can-i-stop-unwanted-notifications-from-google-calendar-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the events for which you get notifications have a reminder set in them. So the easiest way to get rid of the notifications is to turn off the reminders in the events themselves. Typically, you would not have a reminder in the birthday event but if the event came from somewhere else (like Outlook or other phone) then the reminder might get added to it. I had this problem on some phones...
however, it could be very tedious to remove reminders individually if you have many events with unwanted reminders.

The second part of the question: I'd use [Tasker app](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) for that. However, you have to pay for it. I am aware of a free automation app AutomateIt (*sorry can't add a link because I don't have enough rep here*) and from description it looks like it can also kill sound based on a rule but I have not used it myself so will not comment. 
For Tasker there are [instructions](http://tasker.wikidot.com/sleepmode) on how to implement "*Sleep mode*" with which the phone with "shut up" at night. If you go down this path I can assist more since I have set this up on my phone and it works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

I've just published the new version of Nudnik Calendar Notifications.
This app integrates seamlessly with your Google Calendar. There is a quiet hours feature so you can set not to be notified for certain hours. You will get the notifications when the quiet hours are over.

Check it out - it has the best nag features (popup, sound, led, vibrations) + other cool stuff like Shake-to-stop/snooze, notify events without reminders, quite hours, and much more!

https://market.android.com/details?id=amProgz.nudnik.full

Thanks :)

Comment: Please be sure to read the [FAQ#promotion] about promoting your own products.

Answer (score 1):

if it's an HTC, theres an option to set "Reminders" to "None" instead of the default 10 minutes. it's just under the "Description" box in the new event screen.

****************i'm stupid.
You said Google calendar, i skipped that part when reading the post title.

If you go to your online calendar (google.com/calendar) you can edit the event and click the "x" next to "Reminders", and that will remove the alarm on your calendar (and device, as long as device syncs).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, if only there was a setting in Google calendar for turning of reminders for all-day events...

Comment: Scratch that, in fact you can. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17824/how-can-i-stop-unwanted-notifications-from-google-calendar-on-an-iphone

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: select *All day event*, type 0 and the time when you wish to be notified.

[image]